# Googletrans not detecting language

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit, googletrans

Good morning everyone,

I am using googleTrans in my code to translate a list of sentence. It worked perfectly until today. Now when I run it, it perceive everything as English and then not making any translation.
One classical code I tried to do a test:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
results =translator.translate('हॅलो वर्ल्ड')
print(results.text)
```

Which is printing "हॅलो वर्ल्ड". Same with french sentences or other languages.

```
translation = translator.translate("Hola Mundo")
print(f"{translation.origin} ({translation.src}) --> {translation.text} ({translation.dest})")
```

Is giving: "Hola Mundo (en) --> Hola Mundo (en)"

My text is in different language so I cannot set one input language.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

googletrans uses not the official API. It uses the Google Translate Ajax API.
You can also read this in the [docs](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-on-library-usage).
If you make too many requests, especially one right after another, you will be banned.

Turn on exceptions and you will see that you get the HTTP Error [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429):

```
>>> from googletrans import Translator
>>> translator = Translator(raise_exception=True)
>>> print(translator.translate('हॅलो वर्ल्ड').text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
Exception: Unexpected status code "429" from ['translate.googleapis.com']
```

**What can you do?** Do not make too many requests or use the [official API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).